# Metal Alpha value of Color not changing

Tags: metal, metalkit

```
fragment half4 fragment_shader(VertexOut vIn [[stage_in]]){
    return half4(1,1,0.75,0.0);
}
```

In the Sample Drawing Triangle program for each vertices I am passing this fragment Shader.

Since Alpha is Zero There shouldnot be any output. Changing Alpha Not Working

Output not changing with Alpha Change

Comment: The alpha value of the color you return from your fragment shader doesn't have any effect unless you [enable blending](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Render-Ctx/Render-Ctx.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH7-SW22).

Comment: Thanks.. Worked !